# Can I use hibernate entity annotations with bean validation

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, annotations, jsf-2

To use bean validation for form fields in JSF 2, you can use annotations in the bean like `@Length(max=5)`.

However, since these constraints are already defined in my Hibernate entity object, for example: `@Column(name = "FIELDX", length = 5)`, I was wondering if there's a way to use them for the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. And you shouldn't, because:

- validation logic might change while field definition is retained
- only a few of the constraints can be mapped to column definitions

Comment: well this brings up the question of "should the db match the bussiness validation(as much as it can ofc)". What do you think, Bozho?

Comment: @Liviu T. it should, but it can't be as strict. Every layer should perform its own validation.