# Spring form bean replacement with entity class in spring + hibernate project

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

Currently I am going after spring and hibernate project in which we have three layers. Controller, Service and Repository. We have annotation based entity class for mapping table.

My question is can we remove formbean class and replace it with entity class ( for validation and getting form values) and is that a good practice. Since I am writing same variables for both class and repeating the code.

Here is the example in which the author has used Entity class as form beans instead of writing form bean class separately in dto package.

[link](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven-crud/)

Comment: It's fairly standard to use the Entity as a DTO for binding the form data and makes no technical difference when using Spring MVC.

Comment: @geoand Please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718627/can-i-use-hibernate-entity-annotations-with-bean-validation) this do not recommend it.

Comment: I totally agree with answer below!

Comment: @geoand So in long run also it is feasible from maintenance point of view.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little opiniated but I it is hard not to be with such a question.

In my applications, I mainly use entity classes as DTO (without dedicated form beans) when it is *natural*, ie when all the fields of the form are a simple and single attribute in entity.

I use entity as DTO and dedicated converters, when there is a one to one relation between fields of the form and attributes in entity but with complex rules

I use a form bean as soon as the relation is not a simple one to one and a global converter form bean <-> entity.

But I cannot say those are really good practices, it is just a possibility.

Comment: So there is not such hard and fast rule to write form bean for each and every form we can bind the same with entity class. And also this will be feasible if the projects goes big in future for maintenance